# How to query and join csv data with Hbase data in Spark Cluster in Azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

In Microsoft Azure, we can create Spark cluster in Azure HDInsight and create Hbase cluster in Azure HDInsight. Now I have created this 2 kinds of clusters. For the Spark cluster, I can create a dataframe from a csv file and run an SQL query like this (below query is executed in Jupyter notebook):

```
%%sql
SELECT buildingID, (targettemp - actualtemp) AS temp_diff, date FROM hvac WHERE date = \"6/1/13\"
```

In the meantime, in the spark shell, I can create a connector to another HBase cluster to query data table in that HBase like this:

```
val query = spark.sqlContext.sql("select personalName, officeAddress from contacts")
query.show()
```

so, my question is is there a way to do the join operation against this two tables? For example:

```
select * from hvac a inner join contacts b on a.id = b.id
```

I just reference below 2 documents in Microsoft Azure:

[Run queries on Spark Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-load-data-run-query)

[Use Spark to read and write HBase data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-using-spark-query-hbase?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fhdinsight%2Fspark%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

Any ideas or suggestion for this?